# When deserializing Json string that contains "\" gives Bad Json escape sequence

Tags: c#, json

I have a input field in UI which contains a field Value with "\\test\a\b\c". The Json string in API after serialization has the Value field as below.

```
{
   "ItemKey": "8b603493-3d2d-4903-a054-2abb895ab870",
   "ParentKey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "Schema": "",
   "SchemaTypeName": "",
   "Value": "\\\\test\\a\\b\\c",
   "ValueDefinition": null
}
```

When deserializing this string I get the error,

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(rootElement);

{"Bad JSON escape sequence: \\M. Path 'sample[0].sample[1].Value', line 1, position 3384."}
```

I tried double escaping "\" and this error is resolved.

```
var tempStr = valueReplacement.Replace(@"\\", @"\").Replace(@"//", @"/");
valueReplacement = tempStr.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"/", @"//");

{"Value": "\\test\\a\\b\\c"}
```

But I need the final json that is generated after deserializing to have the value still the same because I need to integrate this with UI.

```
"Value": "\\test\a\b\c"
```

[image]

Is there any way I can change the value again after deserialization?

Comment: you have to post the real json if you want to get the answer

Comment: JIC. I've tried several online json validators and they tell that `{ "Value": "\\test\a\b\c" }` is not a valid json.

Comment: I'm not following.  You have a JSON string that looks like `{"Value": "\\test\a\b\c"}` (you forgot the `{}`).  Then you are trying to deserialize it.  But then you say _"I need the final json that is generated after deserializing"_.  JSON doesn't exist after deserialization; an object does.  What is it that you want

Comment: That JSON string is bad because it contains invalid escape sequences like `\a`. How was it created? That's what needs to be fixed. Was the string generated by concatenating other strings? Any JSON library would have escaped that path.

Comment: @Flydog57 I am trying to integrate an API to UI. So after deserializing by escaping the "\" with "\\" gives the value as { "Value": "\\test\\a\\b\\c" } . But to integrate the final result with UI I need the json result to have value as { "Value": "\\test\a\b\c" }

Comment: @Jess forget deserialization. That string isn't JSON. It can't be parsed by *any* JSON library. The code that created it is broken. That code must be fixed. The field contents should have been `"\\\\test\\a\\b\\c"`. Again, every JSON library would escape backslashes properly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you are right. That is how we get the Json and then when I am deserializing it I get that Bad json escape sequence error.

Comment: @Jess:  Now that you have included valid JSON (that includes `"\\\\test\\a\\b\\c"`), that should deserialize to a string member named `Value` that contains the string you are looking for.  If you look at it in the debugger, you will see the doubled-up \ characters.  However, if you hover over the value in the debugger and press the magnifying glass icon, one of the choices is "Text Viewer".  Pick that and you will see `"\\test\\a\b\c"`

Comment: @Flydog57 yes but I want that value to be \\test\a\b\c in UI.

Comment: Does this boil down to you looking at the debugger representation of the string (which escapes it) instead of the actual string value?

Comment: A string that looks like `"\\\\test\\a\\b\\c"` in the debugger should look like `"\\test\\a\b\c"`